# Error: Cannot find module 'html-webpack-plugin' - Webpack (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, plugins, html-webpack-plugin

I tried to create a basic React app with webpack 4 following this [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75)

until installing "html-webpack-plugin", I did not face any errors. But, once I run the command "npm run start", I keep getting the following error:

```
**Error: Cannot find module 'html-webpack-plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)**
```

I tried to solve this issue using the following two threads by installing packages globally and locally, but it didn't help.

[error: cannot find module html-webpack-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096799/error-cannot-find-module-html-webpack-plugin)

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1330

**Please see my code below:**

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "react_website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Website using React and Webpack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
  })
],
};
```

**- .babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Comment: What I would suggest is , better delete your complete node modules and then try npm install

Comment: I did that, but it did not work!!

Comment: Can you run npm cache clean -f. And check it. It will basically clears the package cache

Comment: UPDATE: I noticed that I cannot see the version for  "html-webpack-plugin". It displays as it is not installed. However, I have installed it, and it is loaded in "package.json" folder.

Comment: Check if it's there in node_modules folder.

Comment: I found that there isn't any folder based on "html-webpack-plugin"

Comment: Yeah, so your package is not getting installed . Please check the log on terminal. If there are any permission issue. Most of the time it's the case. Try install html-webpack-plugin seperately. npm install html-webpack-plugin --save-dev. If not happening try with sudo or with administrative priviledge if you are on windows

Comment: rm -rf node_modules 
npm install
npm i html-webpack-plugin --save-dev
Try this way.

Answer (score 17):

Use this command:

```
npm i --save-dev html-webpack-plugin
```

Comment: I have `html-webpack-plugin` in package.json like OP, but webpack isn't detecting it. I also deleted my node modules and tried the whole thing again. Still nothing. Is there any way to get more info on where webpack is looking?

Answer (score 3):

Try removing Node Modules: `rm -rf node_modules`.

Next re-install all dev dependencies `npm install`.

Lastly, re-install the **html-webpack-plugin** `npm i html-webpack-plugin --save-dev`.

I would also suggest making sure all of the directory paths are correct and that you're inside the actual project folder. This is rare, but can happen from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using typescript, sublime didn't pick it up.  Don't even need to install `@types/html-webpack-plugin`, it already exists.  Just needed to restart the IDE for it to register.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a replacement version to fix the problem

> npm install html-webpack-plugin@4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed a problem by renaming

```
const HTMLWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
```

to

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also resolve error by using below command.

```
npm install html-webpack-plugin
```

Comment: This does not add to the existing answer. In fact, it is worse than the existing answer since you're installing it as a dependency instead of a dev dependency.